# Maven deploying to Tomcat7 (response 403) does not use given plugin correctly

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, deployment

I tried to deploy application through maven with `mvn tomcat:deploy` and it always returned me an error. I was trying to set up it with this :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
      <username>tomcat</username>
      <password>tomcat</password>
      <update>true</update>
      <path>/SpringBatis</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However I found that it is NOT using this settings! Even if I delete this plugin-text I got the same output and it is :

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1f6ea15f]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) charset = ISO-8859-1
[DEBUG]   (f) contextFile = e:\prace\workspace\SpringBatis\target\mitta-webapp\META-INF\context.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) ignorePackaging = false
[DEBUG]   (f) mode = war
[DEBUG]   (f) packaging = war
[DEBUG]   (f) path = /SpringBatis
[DEBUG]   (f) update = false
[DEBUG]   (f) url = http://localhost:8080/manager
[DEBUG]   (f) version = 1.1
[DEBUG]   (f) warFile = e:\prace\workspace\SpringBatis\target\mitta-webapp.war
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/SpringBatis  
[DEBUG] No server specified for authentication - using defaults
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.247 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-03-07T00:11:16+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project SpringBatis: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=%2FSpringBatis&war= -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project SpringBatis: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:70)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=%2FSpringBatis&war=
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:604)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:662)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:295)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:85)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

As you can see, url is not set to `http://localhost:8080/manager/text` but only to `http://localhost:8080/manager`.

---

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBatis</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringMvcExample Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <maxmind.geoip.version>1.2.10</maxmind.geoip.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.10</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- mybatis -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>

        <!-- jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- need this for @Configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>mitta-webapp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
      <username>tomcat</username>
      <password>tomcat</password>
      <update>true</update>
      <path>/SpringBatis</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

tomcat-users.xml

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager-gui,admin-gui,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

---

If I compile it with maven and then just manually load it into tomcat7 it runs fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FOUND IT!!

This was the case : `mvn tomcat7:deploy` instead of `mvn tomcat:deploy`